# How can I handle the error "IndexError: string index out of range"

Tags: python, indexing

I'm trying to read a 2-D table but when I put the values and insert them into the index of the print function, I get an error.

The table is 6x6. Even if I write 1 as column and 1 as line I get the error again.

My code:

```
line = input('Do you wanna the object in the line:...>>>')
column = input('Do you wanna the object in the column:...>>>')
print ('Query line: Column:',column, ' Line:', line, line[int(line)][int(column)])
```

Comment: what is your 2d table called?

Comment: @JoshuaSalazar please write the complete code and define what 2-D table are you referring to !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not given a name to the 2-D table, in my solution I assume it to be `table`.

```
table = [[], [], []]  # some 2-D array
line = int(raw_input("Enter the line: "))
column = int(raw_input("Enter the column: "))
print("Line:", line, "Column:", column, "Item:", table[line][column])
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing your issue is that you are trying to do - `line[int(line)][int(column)]` , access the `line` string as a 2d table, you should give your 2d table's name , instead of line.

Example -

```
table[int(line)][int(column)] #if table is the name of the 2d table otherwise give 2d table's name instead of `table`
```

Answer (score 1):

> IndexError: string index out of range

This errors is simple to explain. Valid indices for a string `str` are in the range `0` to `len(str) - 1` inclusive. You have supplied an index outside that range.

For instance, suppose we have

```
str = 'abc'
```

Then the following are valid: `str[0]`, `str[1]` and `str[2]`. All other indices result in a runtime error.

You need to identify where in your code you supply an invalid index. It appears that would have to be where you write:

```
line[...]
```

you supply an invalid index.

Once you fix that you'll hit the next problem. That is that `line[...]` is a single character and cannot itself be indexed. So even when you fix the outer index, the inner indexing is always invalid.

I don't know what your code is meant to do so cannot tell you how to fix that next problem.